# how to customise this thumbnail slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

In my wordpress website i am using fullwidth thumbnail slider. I am trying to customize it from last 2 day but I am having problems

Here is the link:
http://www.menucool.com/slider/thumbnail-slider-demo-2

I want to achieve:
left slider image 50% on bottom And right slider image 50% on top.
I am attaching image for reference

[image: Something like this]

Comment: Maybe try looking for another slider plugin? What the plugin looks (3D) and what you want (2D and different position) don't really match. Also, don't expect us to just come and show you the code for such a customization, you have to try for yourself and then post it here.

Comment: ^ agree with @yuriy636 . but he can customize by changing some codes in that js file which will css class to previous and next image and then he can add css to these class file.

Comment: I came over 2-3 plugins but i am not able to customize like I shown in image. If you can suggest any plugin like this it ll be great!